# How do I create several private virtual machine images using Azure ARM?

Tags: azure

I want to import a number of  private virtual machines that only I can launch using the ARM REST API.

How do I do that?  I cannot find instructions.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little unclear - do you have a number of already pre-defined virtual machine images that you want to start up, is it multiple copies of the same machine for a load balanced scenario or something else?

Also, you say "Only I can launch" what do you mean by that? By definition, when you describe your resources using Azure Resource Manager, you're essentially making a desired state configuration that you then deploy to Azure, and it will create all those machines for you.

If it's simply a question of creating the configuration file, you can try out cool stuff such as http://Armviz.io to set up your stuff. Alternatively, if you already have a group of resources that you'd like to capture into a script - go here: 
http://capturegroup.azurewebsites.net